# AWS Java SDK not finding profile when using AWS SSO

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, sdk, single-sign-on

I can't reach aws when my login is made using AWS SSO.
I login from my computer using:

```
aws sso login --profile staging
```

The profile is configured like this:

```
[profile staging]
sso_start_url = https://som-nice-working-url
sso_region = us-east-1
sso_account_id = 1234
sso_role_name = the-role-name
region = eu-west-1
output = yaml
```

After doing the login I can access aws through aws cli.

Then I set the varible: `AWS_PROFILE=staging`
But on java I'm getting the following exception:

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain: [EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)), SystemPropertiesCredentialsProvider: Unable to load AWS credentials from Java system properties (aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey), WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider: You must specify a value for roleArn and roleSessionName, com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider@369a95a5: No AWS profile named 'staging', com.amazonaws.auth.EC2ContainerCredentialsProviderWrapper@6d6f6ca9: Failed to connect to service endpoint: ]
```

I have tryed using the ProfileCredentialsProvider with "staging" but the result is the same.

What `CredentialsProvider` should I use?

My code is using the DefaultProviderChain:

```
AWSGlueClient.builder()
            .withRegion("eu-west-1")
            .build()
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 20):

For a Java application you'll need the [SSO Dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/sso).

As of writing the latest is version `2.16.76`

```
// Gradle example
dependencies {
    
    implementation(platform("software.amazon.awssdk:bom:2.16.70"))
    implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:sso:2.16.76")
}
```

You'll also need to set a `default` profile in either `~/.aws/configuration` or `~/.aws/credentials`

More info below:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/credentials.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/setup.html#setup-credentials
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/setup-additional.html#setup-additional-credentials

But, you should also be able to just set the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable to your profile and it should just magically work without the SSO dependency.

In your example, specifically:

```
AWS_PROFILE=staging
```

Comment: Also include `implementation("software.amazon.awssdk:ssooidc")` to avoid the exception: "To use SSO OIDC related properties in the <profile> profile, the 'ssooidc' service module must be on the class path."

Comment: In addition to the above, I had to set AWS_PROFILE explicitly in order to get it to work

Answer (score 8):

In my case, just adding the aws-sso dependency:

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
       <artifactId>sso</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

allows the default credentials providers chain to pick up sso under `ProfileCredentialsProvider`:
[image: Profile credentials provider with sso profile]

To work out of the box, it requires from you to have the `[default]` profile specified. Otherwise, simply using `.credentialsProvider(ProfileCredentialsProvider.create("xyz"))` also works with `[profile xyz]`.

If all fails, add the credentials provider manually:

1. Setup your profile file `.aws/config`
2. Login with cli `aws sso login --profile <your_profile>`
3. A json file is generated in `.aws/sso/cache` with contents as described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sso-temporary-credentials/)

```json
{
 "startUrl": "https://my-sso-portal.awsapps.com/start",
 "region": "us-east-1",
 "accessToken": "eyJlbmMiOiJBM….",
 "expiresAt": "2020-06-17T10:02:08UTC"
}
```

4. Include in your project a dependency to `software.amazon.awssdk:sso`
5. Create `SsoCredentialsProvider` with the data from json file:

```java
CredentialsProvider ssoCredentialsProvider = ((SsoCredentialsProvider.Builder) SsoCredentialsProvider.builder())
.ssoClient(SsoClient.builder().region(<REGION_FROM_JSON>).build())
.refreshRequest( () ->
    GetRoleCredentialsRequest.builder()
      .roleName("<ROLE_FROM_PROFILE>")
      .accountId("<ACCOUNT_ID_FROM_PROFILE>")
      .accessToken("<ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_JSON>")
      .build()
).build();
```

Answer (score 4):

Support for SSO Credentials Provider was added to AWS SDK for Java V2 in version `2.15.33` (**November 2020**). Older versions of the SDK don't work with SSO. (See the [Feature Request](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/issues/1970) & the [PR](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/pull/2118))

If you are using maven, make sure the versions of all SDK modules are compatible by specifying the version in the `dependencyManagement` section as described in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/setup-project-maven.html). e.g.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.8</version>  <!--Must be 2.15.33 or higher-->
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
       </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>dynamodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
       <artifactId>sso</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong, however IMO there is no way to use AWS SSO within AWS SDK yet based on https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v2/developer-guide/credentials.html.

AFAIK AWS SSO is at the moment integrated only into AWS CLI - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/singlesignon/latest/userguide/integrating-aws-cli.html

Answer (score 1):

Waiting for SDK 2 to integrate SSO, `aws-sso-cred-restore` is a workaround:

Intall it (with Python 3):

```
pip3 install aws-sso-cred-restore
```

Then you can run this (it get a Token available for around 1h, so you should run it every hour to refresh):

```
aws-sso-cred-restore --profile $YOUR_PROFILE
```

And you can use again your $YOUR_PROFILE in your Java app.

Comment: when profile is "default" it cannot find it, because the section name is `[default]`

Answer (score 1):

When using AWS SDK for Java, you could try giving some environment variables to your Java applicatation using values from the cached temporary credentials.

Login using:

```
aws sso login
```

Read the cached file:

```
cat ~/.aws/cli/cache/<generated>.json
```

Set your environment variables using fields from the cached file:

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<AccessKeyId>
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<SecretAccessKey>
AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=<SessionToken>
```

Run your Java application using these environment variables.

Under the hood, the EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider class reads these environment variables.

You will need to reset these environment variables every time the session token expires.

Answer (score 1):

This is an enhanced answers's @nluk provided. You just need the iam profile name to get the sso profile from the `.aws` folder and `config` file.

Add this in the pom:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>sso</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.16</version>
        </dependency>
```

then: you can use sdk2 sso tooling:

```java
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.AwsSessionCredentials;
import software.amazon.awssdk.auth.credentials.ProfileProviderCredentialsContext;
import software.amazon.awssdk.profiles.ProfileFile;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sso.auth.SsoProfileCredentialsProviderFactory;

//....
 String awsProfile = "my-profile-name"
 ProfileFile profileFile = ProfileFile.defaultProfileFile();
    profileFile
        .getSection("profiles", awsProfile)
        .ifPresent(
            profile -> {
              ProfileProviderCredentialsContext profileProvider =
                  ProfileProviderCredentialsContext.builder()
                      .profile(profile)
                      .profileFile(profileFile)
                      .build();
//            cast to get the token
              AwsSessionCredentials awsCredentials =
                  (AwsSessionCredentials)
                      new SsoProfileCredentialsProviderFactory()
                          .create(profileProvider)
                          .resolveCredentials();
// then get the temporary credentials
//            awsCredentials.accessKeyId();
//            awsCredentials.secretAccessKey();
//            awsCredentials.sessionToken();
            });
```