# How to authenticate to AWS using Java SDK and SSO

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, aws-java-sdk, aws-credentials

I am trying to find sample code to authenticate to AWS using the Java SDK (auth via SSO).

If anyone has done this and could please share, that would help.

Comment: you can find references here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64062720/aws-java-sdk-not-finding-profile-when-using-aws-sso

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Java SDK not finding profile when using AWS SSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64062720/aws-java-sdk-not-finding-profile-when-using-aws-sso)